# Match column 1 of CSV, and then check if column 2 matches

Tags: bash, csv, compare, match, diff

I currently have a Bash script that scrapes particular info from access logs and writes them to a CSV in the following format:

```
    0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020
    0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,17/Apr/2020
    0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,18/Apr/2020
    0004F2426702,80.111.224.252,18/Apr/2020
    00085D19F072,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020
    00085D20A469,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020
    0018B9FFDD58,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,81.97.142.178,16/Apr/2020
    64167F801BF5,95.97.142.178,18/Apr/2020
    0004F2426702,80.111.224.252,19/Apr/2020
```

But, now I am stuck!

I want to match on column 1 (the MAC address), and then check to see if column two matches. If not, print all the lines where column 1 matched.

The purpose of this script is to spot if the source IP has changed.

Comment: Matches what? Including desired output would help figure out what you want.

Comment: So, for column 1, find all entries with the same MAC address, and then check if column 2/the IP address is the same for each entry.

If not, print the output of each line, ideally transposing the dates.

With 0004F2426702 as an example, I would ideally like the following output:

0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020,17/Apr/2020,18/Apr/2020
0004F2426702,80.111.224.252,18/Apr/2020,19/Apr/2020

Answer (score 0):

Using my favorite tool, GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) to do most of the work of grouping and counting the data:

```
$ datamash -st, -g1,2 unique 3 countunique 3 < input.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $NF > 1 { NF--; print }'
0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020,17/Apr/2020,18/Apr/2020
0004F2426702,80.111.224.252,18/Apr/2020,19/Apr/2020
```

Pure `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = SUBSEP = "," }
       { if (++seen[$1,$2] == 1) dates[$1,$2] = $3; else dates[$1,$2] = dates[$1,$2] "," $3 }
       END { for (macip in seen) if (seen[macip] > 1) print macip, dates[macip] }' input.csv
0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,16/Apr/2020,17/Apr/2020,18/Apr/2020
0004F2426702,80.111.224.252,18/Apr/2020,19/Apr/2020
```

Comment: Your commands worked for that sample, but weren't actually matching for what I wanted. In the sample,2 MACs appear with two different IP addresses., That's wjat I want to spot. 

"datamash -st, -g1 unique 2 countunique 2 < test.csv | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $NF > 1 { NF--; print }'" returns the following, which is the kind of thing I'm after:

        0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,80.111.224.252
        64167F801BF5,81.97.142.178,95.97.142.178

But, obviously, that has no dates associated, so I can't spot how many dates X IP is associated with a given MAC address.

Comment: I think the best desired output possible from the original sample would be as follows:

        0004F2426702,75.214.224.151,3,80.111.224.252,2
        64167F801BF5,81.97.142.178,1,64167F801BF5,95.97.142.178,1

Comment: i.e

MAC,IP_1,Count_of_IP_1,IP_2,Count_of_IP_2,